# How to pause and resume an Android Alarm?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am developping an alarm, which vibrates in time defined intervals. So if I choose 5 seconds, the app will vibrates at each 5 seconds intervals. But I need to stop, pause, and resume the app.

This is my class:

```
public class AndroidAlarmService extends Activity {

private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private Chronometer chronometer;
private Intent myIntent;
AlarmManager alarmManager;
Calendar calendar;
private long mTimeWhenStopped;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startalarm);
    Button buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopalarm);
    Button buttonPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pausealarm);
    Button buttonResume = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resumealarm);

    chronometer = ((Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.clock_time));

    myIntent = new Intent(AndroidAlarmService.this,
            MyAlarmService.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
            AndroidAlarmService.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

I start it in this method:

```
buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            int initialValue = 0;

            chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + initialValue);
            chronometer.start();

            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 5 * 1000, pendingIntent);

            Toast.makeText(AndroidAlarmService.this, "Start Alarm",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

This is used to pause:

```
    buttonPause.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            stopRunning();

            mTimeWhenStopped = chronometer.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

            // Tell the user about what we did.
            Toast.makeText(AndroidAlarmService.this, "Resume!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

I'd like to resume the app from the point it has started.
How can I do that?

Thank, you!

Answer (score -1):

the following link might be helpful to you

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html

Comment: Thank you. But this is the exactly link I am using to do my example.

Comment: try resetting the alarm once it has stopped instead of resuming